# click on image to dispatch event in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a image in renderer class and if i click image i need to dispatch a event to the main mxml page in flex.

**In Renderer Class:-**

```
public function clickOnMoreImage(event:Event):void {                
    var moreImageEvent:Event = new Event("clickOnMoreImage");
    var parent:EventDispatcher = parentDocument.parentDocument as EventDispatcher;
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.dispatchEvent(moreImageEvent);
    }
}


<mx:Image id="imgStatus" buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" click="clickOnMoreImage(event)" />
```

**parent class:-**

```
this.addEventListener("clickOnMoreImage", showMoreImagePopUpData);

public function showMoreImagePopUpData(event:Event):void {
    Alert.show("clicked on More Image");
}
```

This is not working. can i know any work around for this?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193665/spark-list-with-buttons/7193979#7193979

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use `parent` or `parentDocument` in this case. You cannot be sure of nesting level of your renderer against top application.
2. The "Flex" way is to use [event bubbling](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html).

Dispatch event by renderer itself (with `bubbles` set to `true`). It will "bubble" (in case the renderer is not a child of a popup) up to stage, so you can listen to it in any parent of the renderer (e.g. -> DataGroup -> List -> Application -> SystemManager -> Stage).

```
var moreImageEvent:Event = new Event("clickOnMoreImage", true); //2nd parameter "true"
dispatchEvent(moreImageEvent);
```