# Accessing Dataprovider arraycollection

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, dataprovider

How to access dataprovider arraycollection from custom ItemRenderer class related to that DataProvider?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dirty way in custom ItemRenderer:

```
if (owner.hasOwnProperty("dataProvider")) trace( owner["dataProvider"] );
```

But i wouldn't recommend to do so. ItemRenderer shouldn't have a reference to the parent or parent properties.

Comment: So if you want to communicate between the two, use events. Some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193665/spark-list-with-buttons/7193979#7193979, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925474/create-dropdownlist-with-delete-button-in-this-itemrenderer/8928105#8928105