# Click on a button inside List component also selects the item

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, itemrenderer

I have `List` component with `ItemRenderer` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7193979). When I click on a `Button` inside this renderer - list item is also becomes selected. I don't want it to be.

I also tried my own `ItemRenderer` which I actually want to use. Here's the code:

```
<s:ItemRenderer 
            width="130"
            dataChange="dataChangeHandler(event)"
            clipAndEnableScrolling="false"
            xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
            autoDrawBackground="true"
            xmlns:model="....model.*"
            xmlns:components="....components.*"
            creationComplete="{spinner.play()}">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.core.UIComponent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        // Variables
        // 
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Status of the preview item: undefined, discarded or approved.
         */
        private var actualPreviewStatus:String = "";

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        // Handlers
        // 
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        protected function dataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            //In Callas version we don't need to handle different statuses.
            if (data && actualPreviewStatus != data.status)
            {
                actualPreviewStatus = data.status;
                switch (data.status)
                {
                    case PrintItem.STATUS_UNDEFINED:
                    {
                        //indicator.styleName = "";
                        break;
                    }
                    case PrintItem.STATUS_DISCARDED:
                    {
                        //indicator.styleName = "itemDiscardedStyle";
                        //itemStatus.text = resourceManager.getString("localization", "ThumbnailsArea.ItemDiscarded");
                        AppEventBus.instance.dispatchAppEvent(AppEvent.ANIMATE_PREVIEW_DISCARD, localToGlobal(new Point(indicator.x, indicator.y)));
                        break;
                    }
                    case PrintItem.STATUS_APPROVED:
                    {
                        //indicator.styleName = "itemApprovedStyle";
                        //itemStatus.text = resourceManager.getString("loclization", "ThumbnailsArea.ItemApproved");
                        AppEventBus.instance.dispatchAppEvent(AppEvent.ANIMATE_PREVIEW_APPROVE, localToGlobal(new Point(indicator.x, indicator.y)));
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        protected function image_updateCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            if((event.target as Image).width != 0)
                spinnerContainer.visible = false;
        }

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup 
          width="100%"
          paddingLeft="13"
          verticalAlign="middle"
          gap="3">

    <mx:Text width="100%"
             text="{(data as PrintItem).label}"/>
    <!-- preview item thumbnail -->
    <mx:Image 
              maxWidth="90" maxHeight="60"
              source="{(data as PrintItem).source}"
              scaleContent="true"
              maintainAspectRatio="true"
              updateComplete="image_updateCompleteHandler(event)"/>
    <mx:Text id="itemStatus"
             width="100%"
             styleName="smallText"/>

</s:VGroup>
<s:Group
         id="spinnerContainer"
         width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill><s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF" /></s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <components:Spinner id="spinner"
                        verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" />
</s:Group>

<s:Button
    label="test"
    click="button1_clickHandler(event)"
    alpha="1.0"/>
<!-- preview item status indicator -->
<s:Button id="indicator"
          y="37"
          visible="false"
          mouseEnabled="false"
          skinClass="com.pms.approvaltool.skins.ImageButtonSkin"/>
```

And here's how I initialize my list (it's custom, but there just 1 property added to prevent keyboard navigation):

And it works exactly the same - when I click on a button the list item becomes selecte.
How can I make it work normally so `Button` intercepts all mouse events over it?

Comment: Do you still need to be able to select a list item if the user clicks something other than the `Button`?

Comment: Yes, but I found a solution - add mouseDown event listener to the button and stop even propognation there. Doing that in clicl listener for example doesn't work. Seems like selection is coming from mousDown event.